# Access denied when principal set to aws lambda.amazonaws.com

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I access a bucket with a lambda function and i get an "Access Denied" error, when i access it with a lambda function via boto3. If i set principal to "*" in the Bucket, all works fine. What is the issue?

```
 "Sid": "DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
...
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your current configuration? Are you referring to a Bucket Policy, or a policy attached an IAM Role, or the Trust Policy of the IAM Role (confusing, eh!). The correct configuration should be an IAM Role that trusts the Lambda service, which grants access to `s3:GetObject` (at a minimum).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Bucket policy

Answer (score 1):

In the bucket policy, the principal to give allow permission to should be the lambda execution role and not the lambda service (lambda.amazonaws.com).

Adding more details, if the lambda execution role is in the same AWS account as the bucket, then an allow permission in the role should suffice. As long as there is no explicit deny in the bucket policy.

However, if the role and bucket are in separate accounts, the role has to have allow permission and the bucket policy has to give allow permission to the role.

Comment: if i put the role in it, i get an "invalid policy" error

Comment: Can you paste your bucket policy so I can inspect? Also coming back to the additional details I mentioned. Do you really need to add a bucket policy? Because if this is not cross-account access you don't really need a bucket policy for a lambda function to access the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

The steps would be:

- Create an IAM Role with a use-case of **Lambda** (this creates a Trust Policy that allows the AWS Lambda service to assume the role)
- Add a Policy to the IAM Role that grants the required Amazon S3 permissions
- Configure the AWS Lambda function to use this IAM Role

There is no need to use an Amazon S3 Bucket Policy for your stated requirements.

As a general rule, Bucket Policies are used when granting permission to everyone, and IAM policies should be used when granting access to specific Users or Groups. (However, there can be other situations for using Bucket Policies, such as granting cross-account access.)

Comment: But should i not try to limit the access for only this lambda function in order to have the least permission?

Comment: The default situation is that nobody has permissions anywhere. Then, you can create IAM Users and IAM Roles and grant permission to them to access services and resources. So, the simplest way to ensure least permission on the bucket is to not assign permission to anyone for the bucket in the first place. Then, only this IAM Role would have access. This, of course, is made more difficult if you assign `s3:*` permissions to Users and Roles (never a good practice!), in which case a `Deny` policy would be required. However, you don't mention any such security requirements in your questions.

Comment: Why cant i just take the standard role the lambda function is using?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking in your last comment.  If you have any particular security goals, feel free to update your question with the details.